# how to send response to ajax but keep procces php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i have an idea to my project, im using ajax as front and laravel as back here.

for example when processing images.

the step to proccess images is like this.

1. upload images
2. validate images
3. compress images
4. finish

so, on user side, i want to show that report each php script is finish proccess the task.

for example when php finish upload image then i want to return message to user that upload is complete and then next step is validate image and more...

what i know is, to return response to ajax is by using

```
public function upload_image(Request $request){
    //script to upload image...
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'true',
        'state' => '1',
        'msg' => 'upload image'
    ]);

    //script to checking images and more...
}
```

and sure this will stop continue proccess after return.

is there a way to return response to user but keep continue procces the php script?

Comment: Yes, using [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues).

Comment: You can also read up on Sockets.

Comment: Yes! there are several ways to do that with js, curl, and ajax. here is a simple example for progress bar which is showing percentage, it could be done for returning more infos about file during upload. Session Upload Progress https://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/ there are tons of examples on internet.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not way to return success and continue executing scripts.

The most common way doing that is to use queues and jobs, check more here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Another way depends on your app logic. If you are sure that user will stay after success you can split up your request and when image is uploaded return image identifier and make another response to manipulate on it, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/upload',
    data: {...},
    success: function(res){
        compressionRequest(res.image);
    }
})
```

Another way is to use sockets like this event flow:

> Send upload event => successfull upload event => user gets success message => server continues manipulations on image

Hope this helps you